# Sublime Text 2: Changing status bar height

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using the SublimeCodeIntel plugin which shows method descriptions based on its docblock in the status bar. The problem is that the status bar is relatively small so the info gets truncated which makes the plugin rather useless in cases were the info is too long. I tried to fiddle around with the "status_bar" entries in the theme configuration but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not exactly what you need, but you can change status bar's font's size, adding something like this:

```
{
    "class": "label_control",
    "parents": [{"class": "status_bar"}],
    "font.size": 15
},
```

to your `.sublime-theme` file.

Of course you can set `font.size` to whatever fits your needs.

Comment: I've tried that one already but this isn't sufficient as the small size makes the text unreadable :/